# How to create ligatures for dashes and quotes in cm-unicode fonts in plain xetex?

Tags: xetex, punctuation, ligatures

Process the following file with `xetex`:

```
\font\tenrm="[cmunrm]" at 10 pt \tenrm
``A''---b--c.
\end
```

[image]

This is the log:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=xetex 2019.8.5)  5 AUG 2019 12:49
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test
(./test.tex [1] )
Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\font\tenrm="[cmunrm]:mapping=tex-text"
```